# How to store multiple values of same data type (an array of objects) in one cell of a MySQL row.?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

We have shifted our project from Google app engine to Apache Tomcat. I have a case scenario in which one client (web/mobile) need to send messages to multiple people depending on task and task-age.

In Google app engine project we made this case scenario possible  using endpoint. We made two pojo class one for company and another for employee, in which employee is child of company. I can declare a list of user and a getter  and setter method in company pojo class to fetch a company details including all employee working in that company from datastore in single query.

Now I have to perform same thing with MySQL in which one row of company table should also have one field of employee containing information  of employee (an array of employee)!!!

How do I capture multiple people (i.e., array of people name) in same filed of a MySQL table??

Comment: It's most times a bad idea to do that. Use another table and insert a row for each value.

Comment: Don't. Create a separate table, and add a foreign key.

Comment: thank you vary much for your answers @VMai and  dasblinkenlight !!!what i want to ask is it is our project requirement,we dont want to spend too much of server time to process!!!can you suggest me any solution of this!!!

Comment: one solution i have knowladge is to parse  array in to json string and store it as a string in DB!!!!

Comment: can i use json to parse array in to json string and store it as a string in DB? would this be a viable solution from the prospective of performance and resource utilization?

Comment: You would have much more flexibility if you have your data on a separated table. If it's a JSON string then you're stuck with the same data all the time and might not be able to reuse it elsewhere.

Comment: Again, don't. It is a cardinal requirement of third normal form that rows do not contain arrays. Reconsider, redesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql has introduced a `group_concat()` function a while ago. I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
select
  c.id as company,
  group_concat(e.id) as employees
from
  companies c
left join
  employee e on e.company_id = c.id
group by
  e.company_id
```

Your result will look like:

```
company | employees
------------------------------------
   1     1,2,3,4
   2     5,6,7,8
```